# how to use svn and netbeans for a shared hosting with cPanel control panel

Tags: svn, svn-server

I have a website hosted in a shared environment.

I have seen people using svn with netbeans as ide which will update directly to the server and we can checkout (download the same from a different place) in any place either in office or from home to continue working...

Is it possible to setup svn in shared hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans can surely help you use SVN inside but committing the changes you need svn server. In cPanel server you can install svn server and you can commit to it from your IDE. If you are using shared server, you need to ask your system administrator to install svn on the server and create a repository for you. Then you can use that repository to commit and checkout to/from any number of places you want (as long as you provide correct credentials).

However, cPanel needs not to be related with SVN, for your purposes at least.

[Note: why not you upgrade yourself to use git (http://git-scm.com) and you can use http://github.com and many other to host your projects]

Comment: i have a website and i update files from 4 places... that is the reason i asked for svn...

Comment: alright, you can surely keep using svn for your purpose. there are some free svn hosting sites too. as long as you have a svn server, you can commit/checkout from any number of places you want. however, please give git a try, and i'm sure you will love it.